# Popup open on pageload using hashed URL

Tags: java, php, popup, phpmailer

I'm trying to blast an email with a hashed url i.e. `domain.com/#tellafriend` to open a popup box with a tell a friend `phpmailer`. I have the function to open the popup `"TellAFriend_OpenForm`" which is applied to a button and works. My current var and trigger combo:

```
var thisHash = location.hash;
if(location.hash) 
{
$(#tellafriend).trigger(TellAFriend_OpenForm);      
}
```

But it's not working. I'm missing something, is it my syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You missing quotes.

```
$('#tellafriend').trigger(TellAFriend_OpenForm);
```